# Взаимодействие с элементами другой страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Допустим есть две страницы, хранящиеся в одной папке. На каждой странице есть по две кнопки. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопок на первой странице исчезали обе кнопки на второй странице через функцию ?
(свойство кнопки для её "невидимости", если кнопке задать определенный класс :

```
var btn2 = document.getElementsByClassName("but");
    for(let i=0; i<2; i++){ 
          btn2[i].style.display = "none";
    }
```

)

Comment: допустим что javascript выполняется только на той странице которая открыта а если надо что то сделать на другой странице то это на другой технологии

Answer (score 0):

локально пожалуй никак.

На любом работающем сервере можно сделать взаимодействие через куки. типа такого:

эта страничка будет "командовать парадом" (в примере просто сохраняет текст в куку)

```
<input id="input" type="text"/>
<input type="button" value="пресс ми" onclick="setCookie()"/>
<script>
function setCookie(){
    document.cookie = "mycookie="+document.getElementById("input").value;
}
 
</script>
```

и принимающая страница (с определенным интервалом нашу куку просматривает и выводит в инпут)

```
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<script>
 setInterval(()=>{
    document.getElementById("input").value=document.cookie;
 },500)
</script>
```